# wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted

Tags: linux, wget, busybox

while doing wget from BusyBox v1.23.1 getting an error :

wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted

wget call :

```
wget http://182.72.194.130:7777/device_mgr/device-mgmt/app/cnc/sno/SCNC12J001/updates?cur_fw_ver=1.1(0)7&cur_config_ver=1.0
```

But when I tried , within ubuntu it worked. How can it be resolved?

Comment: wget on bb is very limited. From it's sources: 202 Accepted: "The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed". Treat as success

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Code [202](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202)

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 202 Accepted response status
>   code indicates that the request has been received but not yet acted
>   upon.

can mean "got your request okay but the resource is not yet ready"
e.g. a tape archive needs to be mounted.  Best to try again a while later.  When you repeated your request on Ubuntu the resource was probably mounted.

Wget has some retry parameters you can play with to delay a follow request: see here https://superuser.com/questions/493640/how-to-retry-connections-with-wget/689340#answer-689340